# How to compute the fees of a block

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, block, fee

Having a **block** with all the extrinsics/events, what code should I write (preferably using polkadotJs) to compute the **total amount of fees** paid?

Answer (score 4):

here you go:

```
const at = await api.rpc.chain.getFinalizedHead();
const block = await api.rpc.chain.getBlock(at);
const blockFees = await Promise.all(block.block.extrinsics.map(
    (ext) => api.rpc.payment.queryInfo(ext.toHex(), at.toHex()))
);
blockFees.forEach((x) => console.log(x.partialFee.toHuman()))
```

Although, note that this does not take tips into account.

Comment: This doesn't work for extrinsic where the fees are refunded (like: `parachainSystem.enactAuthorizedUpgrade`), do you have a better solution ?